# alternative to taskkill using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to kill a program in Python without using Taskkill. Basically I have programs which when closed properly (using the X) write diags and clear buffer files. However when using Taskkill, the program is killed instantly and no diags are written and the program cannot recover in future startup.

Comment: that's because you're using TASKKILL "/F" option probably.

Comment: The whole point of force killing is to take control away from the process. In other words you can't do what you want, force kill situation cannot be handled. So in order to solve that you have to assume at the program start that it was forcefully killed earlier **and** that it can be forcefully killed at any time. This obviously makes everything a lot more complicated (atomic complex operations with crash recovery are often hard to implement). The alternative would be to avoid shared state to begin with. Or delegate it to a well known software, e.g. a database.

Comment: Hi Freakish. So the only program close in Python is Taskkill which cannot close a program safely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question was to not use a force Taskkill. I used the below to end the task gracefully.

```
os.system("TASKKILL /IM " + full_server_exe_name)
```